# Random domain temporary email service

Tags: email

I need a temporary email to register on one web service and not to receive spam later. But the thing is that they block emails from all known temporary and public email services. Is there a temporary email provider which registers a random domain, provides an email for temporary use and then cancels the domain?

Comment: Sorry, questions about web services are off-topic on Super User. I recommend you try our sister site dedicated to [web applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), currently in public beta.

Comment: There is probably a good reason why they block those kinds of services. And what you are describing could never happen, as it costs money to register a domain, and the domain generally isn't available for 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The only service I can think of is [10minutemail.com](http://www.10minutemail.com). However, like the name suggests, you only have the address for 10 minutes. It is great for registering for sites and/or services, but obviously, do not expect to get communications at a later date.

If you want to always communicate with this company and just not get spam, take a look for another free email address which happens to be new / unknown - e.g. type free email hosting in to Google and start looking at page 10!

Comment: Thank you. But I need a random _domain_ email address to squeeze through their filters.

Comment: @user - this is what 10 minute mail does.

Comment: No. Let me explain. I need an email like user@<random>.com, and not the one like <random>@constant.com

Comment: @user - 10 minute mail has LOTS of domains and they randomly change what one you will be assigned - I have never had a 10 minute mail address which appears on a filter. Just try it!... or are you saying you need to access this account in the future?... 10minutemail provides <random>@<random>.com

Comment: Tried several times. I always got <something>@bofthew.com, not any other domain.